# SP2013 VS WF - add process dynamically

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, custom-actions

I'm using **VS2013** to create **SP2013 Workflow**. I need to provide user with ability to choose additional approvers while **WF** is running.
For example, normal approval process route is

User A -> User B - > User C

User B may decide that other users also need to be included in a process, so he adds them before or after himself

User A -> **User Z** -> User B -> **User X** - > User C

Is it possible to achive this scenario in SharePoint 2013 Workflow? So far I'm thinking about custom action that will utilize **SPList EventReceivers** instead of WF Task action.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but, it'll add a few extra steps to your Workflow.

If you are using the "SingleTask" activity you should have the TaskID for the task that was created. Create this task targeting a content type that has a Person or Group field that will be used to collect the extra approver.

With the TaskID you can read information that was filled in the task form, after the user completed the task. You can use the REST API or the Get List Item activities to see if extra users were targeted during the approval process and provision the necessary tasks.

If you make this into a custom activity you can get quite a bit of reuse out of these steps.